# Как отправить картинку через ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование, ajax-load

Есть форма:

```
<form class="register_form" action="" method="post" name="reg_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input type="text" placeholder="Фамилия" name="last_name" id ="last_name" required> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Отчетсво" name="middle_name" id ="middle_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Телефон" pattern="0-9]" name ="phone_number" id = "phone_number" required>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Ведите email" name = "email" id = "email" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Отдел" name="department" id = "department" required>    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" name = "login" id = "login" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Пароль" name="password" id = "password" required>
                    <div style = "color: #bd3c2e;" id="errorBlock">aaa</div>
    <button type = "button" class="adduserbtn" value="reg" name="reg" id = "reg">Добавить пользователя</button>
    <div class="file-upload">
        <label for="file-input">
            <img class="addfile" src="./img/avatar.png">
        </label>
        <input id="file-input" type="file" name ="avatar" />
    </div>
</form>
```

И есть ajax скрипт отправки этой формы

```
$('#reg').click(function() {
    var login = $('#login').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
    var middle_name = $('#middle_name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var phone_number = $('#phone_number').val();
    var department = $('#department').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'processing/registration.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {login, password, first_name, last_name, middle_name, email, phone_number, department},
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'Готово'){
                $('#errorBlock').text(data);
            }else{
                $('#errorBlock').text(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Если с отправкой текста я разобрался, то с отправкой картинки/файла не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне нужно сделать для отправки file-input

Comment: [Using jQuery & AJAX for File Upload Form](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/#jquery) По большому счету всё сводится к использованию объекта [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) + для jquery некоторые параметры отключить